# ActiveRecord 4 cannot retrieve "select AS" field

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Ok, I feel really stupid for asking this, but it's driving me nuts and I can't figure it out. The docs say I should be able to use `select AS` in a Rails/ActiveRecord query. So:

```
d = Dvd.where(id: 1).select("title AS my_title")
```

Is a valid query and if I do a `to_sql` on it, it produces the expected SQL:

```
SELECT title AS my_title FROM `dvd`  WHERE `dvd`.`id` = 1
```

However, `d.my_title` will give an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `my_title' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation
```

I need to be able to use `AS` since the columns I want to retrieve from different joins have the same name so I can't access them the "regular" way and have to resort to using `AS`.

I also don't want to resort to using `find_by_sql` for future compatibility and a possible switch form Mysql to PostGresql.

Just to clarify, what I'm really trying to do is write this SQL in a Railsy way:

```
SELECT tracks.name AS track_name, artists.name AS artist_name, composers.name AS composer_name, duration 
  FROM `tracks_cds` 
  INNER JOIN `tracks` ON `tracks`.`id` = `tracks_cds`.`track_id` 
  INNER JOIN `artists` ON `artists`.`id` = `tracks_cds`.`artist_id` 
  INNER JOIN `composers` ON `composers`.`id` = `tracks_cds`.`composer_id` 
  WHERE cd_id = cd.id
```

The top example was just a simplification of the fact that `SELECT AS` will not give you an easy way to refer to custom fields which I find hard to believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your sql query and then just pass into ActiveRecord's execute method

```
query = "SELECT title AS my_title FROM `dvd`  WHERE `dvd`.`id` = 1"
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

Comment: Not only does your code return an error for `result =` (even if you remove the redundant `execute`, try it) but this is pretty much the same as doing `find_by_sql` which I said I'd rather not do.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord automatically creates getter and setter methods for attributes based on the column names in the database, so there will be none defined for `my_title`.

Regarding the same common names, why not just do this:

```
d = Dvd.where(id: 1).select("dvds.title")
```

Comment: Because I need the custom field to retrieve it's value and create a JSON hash out of it. I'll edit my original post for more clarity.

Comment: @kakubei why not just override `as_json` in your model to render the JSON how you want?

Comment: we're doing that already, but it doesn't save me from having to extract that data out of the database in an optimum way. I still have the "select as" dilemma. Also, note that I have solved it by using find_by_sql. Just wanted a more Railsy way of doing it.